# Importing class to JSF2 view to get the qualified name

Tags: java, jsf-2, xhtml

I did this in a JSP:

```
<%@ page
    import="org.example.applet.MyApplet"%>
<%

<div class="panel-body">
    <object type="application/x-java-applet"
        classid="java:<%=MyApplet.class.getName()%>.class"
        height="600" width="900">
        ...
        Applet failed to run. No Java plug-in was found.
    </object>
</div>
```

How can I "print the class name into the html/jsf2 view (in a xhtml)? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a getter function in your applet as:

```
public String getClassName(){
    return this.getClassName();
}
```

then you need to call it as MyApplet.getClassName().

Comment: Is there no easier way? So much boilerplate code! So MyApplet needs to be a Spring-Component/EJB-Bean?